# Adding a test to Trix, helper method is not a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript, qunit, trix

For my job, I've had to fork the [Trix WYSIWYG](https://trix-editor.org/) editor and start adding new features that I know won't be accepted into the base project. I've got a feature working that allows a user to left/right align an embedded image in the editor.

My question is about a test. The Trix codebase uses QUnit, and has a series of system tests with custom helpers. For context: I am a Rails backend developer. This is not my area and my implementation is likely very clumsy.

I've added a system test that uses the same format as the other tests in the file it's in, and am struggling to understand why I'm getting an error.

So one of their tests, that I did not write and which passes consistently, is written like this:

```
{after, assert, clickElement, defer, dragToCoordinates, moveCursor, pressKey, test, testGroup, triggerEvent, typeCharacters} = Trix.TestHelpers

... 

test "editing an attachment caption with no filename", (done) ->
  after 20, ->
    # asserts about caption content

    clickElement getFigure(), ->
      # assertions about caption content after clicking on figure
      done()
```

All of the tests in this file follow a similar format of using a callback passed as the second argument in `test` (usually it's `done`) and calling `after 20, ->` before the contents of the test.

There are two relevant helper functions I've found related to how this test is written. One is in a file *test/src/test_helpers/test_helpers.coffee*

```
helpers = Trix.TestHelpers

# a few functions

helpers.extend
  test: (name, callback) ->
    QUnit.test name, (assert) ->
      doneAsync = assert.async()

      ready (element) ->
        done = (expectedDocumentValue) ->
         if element?
           if expectedDocumentValue
             assert.equal element.editor.getDocument().toString(), expectedDocumentValue
           requestAnimationFrame(doneAsync)
         else
           doneAsync()

         if callback.length is 0
           callback()
           done()
         else
           callback(done)
```

And then there's this `after` function in *test/src/test_helpers/index.coffee* (along with the `defer` function, which is also used by the other passing tests):

```
# Remove QUnit's globals
delete window[key] for key, value of QUnit when window[key] is value

Trix.TestHelpers = helpers =
  ...
  after: (delay, callback) ->
    setTimeout(callback, delay)

  defer: (callback) ->
    setTimeout(callback, 1)
```

So I went ahead and added a test for my new functionality right after the previous "editing an attachment with no filename" test:

```
test "aligning and re-aligning an attachment", (done) ->
  after 20, ->
    # some assertions
    clickElement getFigure(), ->
      # define left/right/clear alignment buttons
      clickElement leftAlignButton, ->
        # assertion
      defer ->
        clickElement clearAlignButton, ->
          # assertion
        defer ->
          clickElement rightAlignButton, ->
            # assertion
            done()
```

This (80-90% of the time, *but not always*) fails, with the error: "Uncaught TypeError: after is not a function", and then the test (*just* my test) proceeds to time out. When I remove the call `after 20, ->`, the test passes (all of the other tests that I didn't write always pass).

So obviously I could just remove `after 20, ->`, but then I'm left with the conundrum of why *my* test is failing on something that clearly works for the other tests. When it comes to callbacks and timeouts, I've only just been reading [You Don't Know Javascript's](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) section on asynchronous code this past week, so I'm certain the problem is my inability to clearly grasp how the test suite is using callbacks, but for the life of me I can't work it out.

Comment: I don't have time right now for a full answer, but I also think this is an async problem. My guess is that it only fails some of the time because sometimes that defer happens slightly faster than the 20ms, and sometimes it doesn't. In any case, I think this is just a race-condition thing, but not entirely sure where/how.

Comment: (Also... geez I hate coffeescript... so hard to read.)

Comment: Heh. Don't blame you.

Comment: Anyway, if that's true, then something's off in my understanding of the event loop? My understanding was that all defer is doing is saying, 'Make sure this happens *after* everything else in the event loop'. So what's happening after twenty seconds is everything up to 'defer', but then defer is saying, 'don't let this happen until everything else is finished'. So how is it possible that defer runs before after? Or even at the same time? (I'll go brush up on my reading. Just leaving the comment in hopes of possible guidance.) (Comment editing time limit got the best of me there.)

Comment: Well... you initiate a timeout for 20ms, and _inside_ that you do the `defer` calls, so it seems the timeout is actually outside of this issue. The `defer` function does appear to be doing what you suspect (execute the callback after the event loop clears), but since you say that the test passes _some_ of the time, I still suspect a race condition having to do with async deferrals. :/ (This is why I added a comment and not an answer, I don't have a good one for you.)